# Jinja template loop issue

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible

I have a jinja template for the adding elastic search host name based on the variables defined in the host file, but its not taking working for the condition.

My template

```
discovery.seed_hosts: [{% for es_host in ansible_play_hosts if hostvars[inventory_hostname].type == 'master' %} "{{ es_host }}" {%- if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}]
```

My host.yml

```
[sample]
master01 type=master
data01 type=data
```

When I copy the template that is having both master01 and data01 on master 01 even though I am looking only for master type and none in data node.

```
master01
discovery.seed_hosts: [ "master01", "data01"]

data01
discovery.seed_hosts: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if conditional is wrapped around the entire for statement rather than being inside of the loop.  So unless the type of the host you are currently running the play against is "master", the loop won't run, and if it does, it runs against all.  Try this instead:

```
discovery.seed_hosts: [{% for es_host in ansible_play_hosts %} {% if hostvars[es_host].type == 'master' %} "{{ es_host }}"{% endif%}{%- if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}]
```

Comment: Sorry its still behaving the same, After the change now the file is like below

`master01 - on master node
discovery.seed_hosts: [ "master01", "data01"]

data01 - on data node
discovery.seed_hosts: [ , ]`

What i want is 

`master01
discovery.seed_hosts: [ "master01"]

data01
discovery.seed_hosts: ["master01"]`

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem.  Using inventory_hostname in the if conditional of the loop, made it so that if the type of what ever host you were currently configuring was master, then all iterations of the loop were true.  I edited my post above to change it so that it was checking the host currently being iterated in the loop to be the test condition instead.  Try that out and see if it works.